# Show customized Google ads based on user search

Tags: dynamic, ads

We are a recruitment agency, and we have created a job-titles-cities sheet (which contains two columns, one for job titles and the other for cities).

We are using Google Ads for our campaigns.

Our ad is like "hire hospitality staff in London."

We need a way to do the following:

If a user searches for any combination of job titles and cities in the sheet, the ad will appear to them with the relevant {job_title} and {city}.

For example, if they searched for "I need temporary bricklayers in Manchester city", the ad would appear like "Hire bricklayers in Manchester".

How can I achieve that?

We tried creating scripts, and we tried the DKI. I also tried with custom ads, but couldn't determine the result as the upload keeps failing, which is another issue I raised with the ads team, but they took ages to reply. I will address the upload issue in another thread here.

For now, please share your thoughts on how to achieve the desired functionality in Google Ads and whether or not the routes I have taken (bulk script, customized ads, DKI) are the right ones.

Your ideas and help are highly appreciated.